# Hide Menu Icon Button of Appbar of Material UI for only Desktop

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

```
<AppBar title="My AppBar" showMenuIconButton={false} />
```

This Hides the Menu Icon in all devices.

I need to hide only in Desktop.

How Can I achieve this?

Comment: go for css media query, based on screen resolution, decide whether to show or not.

Comment: I want to know if there is a way in Material UI..

Comment: @JefreeSujit has the right idea. I'm not sure how you expect Material UI to know anything about the screen resolution unless you provide it the information You could use javascript to get the screen size if you don't want to use a media query. Store the screenSize in local state or in your Redux store or wherever you want. Even a local variable that gets set when the component mounts. Then just check the size `showMenuIconButton={!!screenSize < 800px}`

Answer (score 1):

You can try this-

```
showMenuIconButton={window.screen.width.<600? true:false}
```

where 600 is 600 pixels.

Answer (score 0):

You can subscribe to resize event listener:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'

const Events = () => {
  const [windowWidth, setWindowWidth] = useState(window.innerWidth)

  useEffect(() => {
    function handleResize() {
      setWindowWidth(window.innerWidth)
    }

    window.addEventListener('resize', handleResize)
    return () => window.removeEventListener('resize', handleResize)
  }, [])

  return (
    <div>
     <AppBar title="My AppBar" showMenuIconButton={windowWidth < 600} />
    </div>
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use **sx** prop attribute for responsive style.

> sx={{ mr: 2, display: {sm: 'none'} }}

```
<IconButton 
         edge="start"
         color="inherit"
         aria-label="menu"
         sx={{ mr: 2, display: {sm: 'none'} }}
>
         <MenuIcon />
</IconButton>
```

AppBar should look like,

```
<Box sx={{display: 'flex'}}>
   <CssBaseline />
   <AppBar
      position="fixed" 
      elevation={1}
   >
     <Toolbar variant="dense">
      <IconButton 
          edge="start" 
          color="inherit" 
          aria-label="menu"  
          sx={{ mr: 2, display: {sm: 'none'} }} 
          onClick={this.handleDrawerToggle}>
              <MenuIcon />
      </IconButton>
      <Typography variant="h6" color="inherit" component="div">
         Logo
      </Typography>
     </Toolbar>
    </AppBar>
    <LeftSideBar  
        handleDrawerToggle={this.handleDrawerToggle} 
        mobileOpen={this.state.mobileOpen} 
    />
</Box>
```